# DLLs missing, application gets 0xc00007b error code

Tags: visual-c++, dll, windows-7

On running my `VC++` application doesn't run and stops with `0xc00007b` error code, which is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. I understand that this means I have problems with some x86 - x64 architecture compatibility issues on `DLL`s.

I have checked with `Dependency Walker` and I get the following: [image]

There is no `64` indicator on any dependency. On double-click on any of the 3 not found files it says it's looking for them in the app folder, although I've copied them there, as well as having *all of them* in `C:\Windows\System32`.

I already have `Visual C++ Redistributables` installed for:

- 2005 - x86 & x64
- 2008 - x86 & x64
- 2010 - x86 & x64

I've run `sfc /scannow` but everything is fine.

The application is `32bit` and it was originally written in `VS2006`, `XP`.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You have a dependency on a Debug MFC DLL, which is not redistributable. You should also try with a Release build to see if you get the same problem.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Towards the end of the trace you get, you'll see your program loading the DLL and taking a nose-dive.

Comment: Release runs without errors, but I still need to be able to debug.

Comment: Will try procmon next.

Comment: If you need to debug, then you need to install Visual Studio. That's the only way you will (legally) get the debug runtimes on your system. There are other ways of debugging release builds, for example like analysing crash dumps against a Release build PDB, but we'd need to know what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  ol der versions of vs (there is no vs2006) the dlls had to be installed in a formal way, not just present.  And, there is no redistibutal package for debug dlls.  You have to install visual studio, or update to vs2010.